# How should I retrieve the data from the code Li?

Tags: jquery

Goal:
Retrieve datatype as a array with data One, two, three and four without using the syntax code "data-id".

Problem:
I tried to find some different solution it didn't go so well. The data can be random.

Info:
This context should be without data-id.

```js
var dataList = $(".list").map(function() {
    return $(this).data("id");
}).get();
console.log(dataList);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li class="list" data-id="123">One</li>
    <li class="list" data-id="124">Two</li>
    <li class="list" data-id="125">Three</li>
    <li class="list" data-id="126">Four</li>
</ul>
```

[**JS FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/RPpXu/)

Thank you!

Comment: What's "datatype"? What exactly is wrong with the code you have now? It seems to run just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're after:

```
var dataList = [];
$(".list").each(function() {
    dataList.push($(this).text());
});
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8mo4e1gx/)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like following without using `data-id`.

```js
var dataList = $(".list").map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
}).get();

console.log(dataList.join('|'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li class="list" data-id="123">One</li>
    <li class="list" data-id="124">Two</li>
    <li class="list" data-id="125">Three</li>
    <li class="list" data-id="126">Four</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I tried the code and you retrieve the value 123|124|125|126 and the request is to retrieve the value one, two, three and four. I did it in my local computer

Comment: I also tried removing the code data-id and I don't retrieve any data in the array. I did it in my local computer

Answer (score 0):

Return your function

```
$(this).attr("data-id");
```

Comment: Why would that work any differently than what he has now?

Comment: without using "data-id"